# Solana Rust: Signature verification failed

Tags: solana-test-validator, transaction, signature, message, verification

I'm getting Solana transaction signature verification error.

I tried many methods but my result is always same, which is "false"

Below is my code:

```
let node_client = RpcClient::new("https://api.testnet.solana.com");
let str_sign = String::from("22XnB7pYjqtJXR5NcTR3E8LuA5Lvf7fvZuvbpRvv8u1n5iSApdZiqYu3vXFezZAM9Z7pTHfo7vBX2Nzyc45TcWco");
let signatures = Signature::from_str(&str_sign).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", signatures);
let get_txn = node_client.get_transaction(
    &signatures,
    UiTransactionEncoding::Json,
);

let send = Pubkey::from_str("4ETf86tK7b4W72f27kNLJLgRWi9UfJjgH4koHGUXMFtn").unwrap();
let send1 = Pubkey::from_str("JE9yw76YsXFacrMJEnvVuHmZXYEPSZpjHsW53c6YkYW7").unwrap();

match get_txn.unwrap().transaction.transaction {
    EncodedTransaction::Json(ui_transaction) => {
        // println!("{:?}", ui_transaction.message);
        match ui_transaction.message {
            UiMessage::Raw(raw_msg) => {
                println!("{:?}", raw_msg);
                let ins_test = CompiledInstruction {
                    program_id_index: raw_msg.instructions[0].program_id_index,
                    accounts: raw_msg.instructions[0].accounts.clone(),
                    data: bs58::decode(&raw_msg.instructions[0].data).into_vec().unwrap(),
                };

                let bsdecode = bs58::decode(&raw_msg.instructions[0].data).into_vec().unwrap();

                let bytes = hex::decode("0200000000ca9a3b00000000").unwrap();
                println!("{:?}", bytes);
                println!("{:?}", bsdecode);

                let msg_test = Message::new_with_compiled_instructions(
                    raw_msg.header.num_required_signatures,
                    raw_msg.header.num_readonly_signed_accounts,
                    raw_msg.header.num_readonly_unsigned_accounts,
                    [send, send1].to_vec(),
                    Hash::from_str(&raw_msg.recent_blockhash).unwrap(),
                    [ins_test].to_vec(),
                ).serialize();

                println!("{:?}", msg_test);

                // let msg_test = Message {
                //     header: raw_msg.header,
                //     account_keys: [send, send1].to_vec(),
                //     recent_blockhash: Hash::from_str(&raw_msg.recent_blockhash).unwrap(),
                //     instructions: [ins_test].to_vec(),
                // }.serialize();
                //
                // println!("{:?}", msg_test);

                let okko = signatures.verify(&send.to_bytes(), &msg_test);
                println!("{:?}", okko);
            }
            _ => {
                println!("Transaction MSG is not in JSON format");
            }
        }
    }
    _ => {
        // Handle other cases if needed
        println!("Transaction is not in JSON format");
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

code modification to get transaction verification by signature

```
{
// compile
let mut ins_test: Vec<CompiledInstruction> = Vec::new();
for instruction in raw_msg.instructions {
    let compiled_instruction = CompiledInstruction {
        program_id_index: instruction.program_id_index,
        accounts: instruction.accounts.clone(),
        data: bs58::decode( & instruction.data).into_vec().unwrap(),
    };
    ins_test.push(compiled_instruction); // Add to the vector
}

// account pub key
let accountKey: Vec<Pubkey> = raw_msg.account_keys.iter().map( | x| Pubkey::from_str(x).unwrap()).collect();
let acc_byte = accountKey[0].to_bytes();

// Construct Serialize message
let message = Message::new_with_compiled_instructions(
    raw_msg.header.num_required_signatures,
    raw_msg.header.num_readonly_signed_accounts,
    raw_msg.header.num_readonly_unsigned_accounts,
    accountKey.clone(),
    Hash::from_str( & raw_msg.recent_blockhash).unwrap(),
    ins_test,
).serialize();

// Verify signature
let okko = signatures.verify( & acc_byte, & message);
println!("Signature Verification: {:?}", okko);
}
```